# How do I set background image using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to set background image using Next.js but I can't.

This doesn't work. The image won't show up:

```
// globals.css

body {
  background: url("/images/grid.svg") repeat;
}
```

I want to repeat the background image on the entire page like this:

[image]

How do I set it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is your images folder? It is in the public folder - right?

Comment: inspect element and see if the image has loaded properly

Comment: @MaulikPatel It's in public folder

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha The image is loaded, it just doesn't show up on actual screen

Comment: Sorry when I changed background color I figured out the image was actually loaded! I just need to figure out how to make it visible as currently it seems like transparent.

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure / screenshot of image being loaded /  minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
background-image: url('/images/grid.svg');
```